# What is the best practice to change MyWSAT page size... css, code, both?

Tags: javascript, css, resize, html

If you load the default MyWSAT page on a computer; you'll notice that it is centered within the page, and that if you resize the page it will dynamically center the content until the page becomes too small...  this behavior works fine for a PC.  On a smart phone however, the content is still centered; however, it would appear there is some "padding / white-space" to either side of the content, which makes the actionable part of the form too small to read or use without resizing the browser window manually...

I've tried different smartphones (Android & iPhone) w different browsers (Android-Native, Safari, Chrome) and they all react the same, as you can see the following images:
[image: MyWSAT.iPhone.Chrome]
[image: MyWSAT.iPhone.Safari]

What is the best practice to change MyWSAT http://mywsat.codeplex.com/ page size...  css, code, both?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, neither...  the solution appears to be an html header directive...

After much searching & experimenting...  I discovered the following was necessary:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

... to the following two files:

> themes/default/default.master
>
> members/themes/default/default.master

This will probably pertain to any web page that is being "scaled" improperly on a mobile device.